# Using enum, Error: org.apache.crunch.CrunchRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Tags: java, bigdata, avro, apache-crunch

When I use custom enum in the crunch `parallelDo` (`Avros.reflects(TestEnumType.class)`) map function, I am getting the below error.

```
Error: org.apache.crunch.CrunchRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:EntityChangeType.<init>() at org.apache.crunch.types.avro.AvroDeepCopier$AvroReflectDeepCopier.createNewInstance(AvroDeepCopier.java:157)
```

Once I change the enum to class, Avro serialization works fine. In both enum and class, I have no argument constructor, and the class is declared static.
How do I serialize the enums using `Avros.reflects` method?

The enum that doesn't work:

```
public static enum EntityChangeType {
    Field1,
    Field2,
    Field3;
   EntityChangeType() {}
}
```

After representing the same enum to the class it works:

```
 public static class EntityChangeType {
    private final String entityChangeStatus;
    public EntityChangeType() {
      this(new String("Field1"));
    }

    public EntityChangeType(String entityChangeStatus) {
     this.entityChangeStatus = entityChangeStatus;
     }

    public String toString() {
      return this.entityChangeStatus;
    }

    public static final EntityChangeType FIELD1 = new EntityChangeType("Field1");
    public static final EntityChangeType FIELD2 = new EntityChangeType("Field2");
    public static final EntityChangeType FIELD3 = new EntityChangeType("Field3");
}
```

Comment: You're missing the most important part of that error. What method does it say does not exist?

Comment: Also I think you have a typo in your enum -- it should say `enum` (not `class`) and the last comma after Field3 should be a `;`

Comment: Corrected the typo mistakes

Comment: you need to add your pom file or how you are importing your dependencies. This is probably related to some missmatch between your dependencies version